# Python - Index out of range in one dimension 1

Tags: python

I have a small piece of code , which when executes gives me an index error.

```
while True:
    for i in range (0,q):
        for j in range (0,q):
            y[i,j] = Y[i,j+1]-Y[i,j]
            z[i,j] = Z[i,j]-Z[i,j+1]
            print "y: "+str(y)
            print "z: "+str(z)
```

q = 10

```
IndexError: index (10) out of range (0<=index<10) in dimension 1
```

I need some help in this.
Thank u.

Comment: What are the definitions of `y`, `Y`, `Z`, it looks like they are numpy arrays?

Comment: @chm, Yes they are numpy arrays.

Answer (score 8):

`j` goes to `9`. Which means that `j+1` goes to `10`. Stop doing that.

Comment: but i want to increment j within that.

Comment: @Ignacio, y[i,j] = Y[i,j+1]-Y[i,j], here am finding the difference between Y[i,j+1]-Y[i,j] were its the difference between last element and the previous one.

Comment: That's nice. You still don't have an eleventh value.

Comment: So how can this be stopped going beyond the range.?

Comment: Go one fewer (Hint: `q-1`).